# how to generate the effect of dotted line under a <tr> element using css?

Tags: css

```
<tr class="dotted">
    <td><strong>Profile Information</strong></td>
</tr>
```

how to write the "dotted" class in css to achieve that effect?

Answer (score 4):

could do

```
tr.dotted td 
{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
}
```

but you'd have to have cellspacing="0" or border-collapse:collapse; set so there are no breaks in the line.

Comment: or, i was wrong and was looking at the post above, it should be 

border-bottom: dotted 1px black;

Comment: You can't use class attribute of parent element to format child's innerHTML.

Comment: Yes you can ... It's called a combinator.